# How do I click a link that has only the "href" unique on a page? Selenium Webdriver - Python

Tags: selenium, python-2.7, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Suppose you have the following list:

```
<ul>
  <li>
      <a class="sameClass" href="link1">Same Text</a>
  </li>
  <li>
      <a class="sameClass" href="link2">Same Text</a>
  </li>
  <li>
      <a class="sameClass" href="link3">Same Text</a>
  </li>    
...
</ul>
```

I want to click the "Same Text" where href="link1".

Note: 
I have already tried multiple css selector and xpath. Non of them worked.
I'm using Selenium 2.27.0

Comment: have you tried
//a[@href='link1' and text()='Same Text']

Comment: @kirschmichel If the link is unique a[@href='link1'] is enough. Why flood with useless text? What if the text strings will be/are localized?

Comment: @Alex Okrushko, as far as I've tested, only a[@href='link1'] did not identify the element as clickable. I needed to click the text, not build the url.

Comment: if the link is **unique** just the `a[@href='link1']` is enough. :) You can try with Firepath in Firebug (Firefox). Secondly, xpath is for selecting element(s) - it has nothing to do with "clickability". In your case, it selects `<a></a>` tag, which you probably use further to  click.

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you want to use CSS selector instead of xpath.

a[href='link2'] or a[href*='partialLink2']

Answer (score 0):

css=a[href='link1']

css=a[href='link2']

css=a[href='link3']

The above are Unique CSS Selectors for the Same Text .

Answer (score 0):

Try using this
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Same Text')]")

where links is the list of all the elements. 
links[0] = link1
links[1] = link2.. so on